# Double Login - Facebook

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, ios-app, facebook

When logging in via Facebook I was taken to the Facebook app. Then approved the stack exchange app and taken back to the chose a login method.

Click Facebook again bounced me to Facebook and back to stack exchange. This time I was successful logged in.

App version: 1.3.2.225
iOS version 9

Comment: Do you have both the beta and App Store version installed? There's a limitation in how Facebook returns to the app, so the flow could have been SEβ -> FB -> SE -> FB -> SEβ.

Comment: It's not installed at the moment, but potential was at one point. Happy to status close.